# Find the MVUE for a uniform parameter

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, statistical-inference, variance, estimation

> Let $Y_{(n)}=\max(Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots,Y_{n})$, where $Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots,Y_{n}$ is a sample uniform distribution in $(0,\theta)$. Find the MVUE for $\theta$.

**My approach:**

1. I know that $U=Y_{(n)}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. I could prove this using the factorization theorem by Neymann.
2. I know that $\displaystyle h(U)=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)U$ satisfy that $\mathbb{E}[h(U)]=\theta$.

So, $$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)Y_{(n)}$$
is a (or the?) MVUE for $\theta$.

---

**My approach is correct? Can I find other MVUE for $\theta$?**

Comment: Rao-Blackwell is a useful tool!

Comment: You can't claim that is the MVUE for $\theta$ **unless** you can show $Y_{(n)}$ is BOTH complete and sufficient. Once you do, use [Lehmann–Scheffé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem).

Comment: @Clarinetist but I could prove that $Y_{(n)}$ is sufficient for $\theta$, so $h(Y_{(n)})=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)Y_{n}$ is the MVUE for $\theta$, since that $\mathbb{E}h(Y_{(n)})=\theta$ or this prove is not valid?

Comment: @Math-fun can you explain me how can I use the Rao-Blackwell theorem here? I read about this, but I don't understand well how can I use that. I would appreciate if you can write an answer with some explanation of that approach.

Comment: I was just opting for a comment not solution :-) ... I think you should check the Rao-Blackwell theorem. check also this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69398/whats-the-difference-between-rao-blackwell-theorem-and-lehmann-scheff%c3%a9-theorem?rq=1

Comment: @Math-fun okis :), I will read that link.

Comment: enjoy the process!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2941489/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, to confirm that $\frac{n+1}{n}Y_{(n)}$ is UMVUE you have only to prove that $Y_{(n)}$ is CSS (Complete and Sufficient Statistic)

- Sufficiency is easy proved observing that

$$L(\theta)=\underbrace{1}_{=h(\mathbf{y})}\times\underbrace{\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbb{1}_{(y_{(n)};\infty)}(\theta)}_{g[t(\mathbf{y}),\theta]}$$

- To prove completeness, as the model does not below to the Exponential family, you must use the definition. Say you have to prove that, for all $g$ measurable and for all $\theta$

$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}g(T)=0\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\theta}[g(T)=0]=1$$

In your case you have

$$0=\mathbb{E}_{\theta}g(T)=\int_0^{\theta}g(t)\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\theta^n}dt=\frac{1}{\theta^n}\underbrace{\int_0^{\theta}g(t)nt^{n-1}dt}_{=0}$$

Now take the derivative w.r.t. $\theta$ obtaining

$$0=\frac{1}{\theta^n}g(\theta)n\theta^{n-1}=\frac{ng(\theta)}{\theta}$$

Thus actually expectation =0 implies also $g=0$ and $Y_{(n)}$ is complete

Now you have only to apply the following theorem

[image]

Comment: That was an excellent explication. Thank so much!

Comment: If the model belong a exponential familly, so how could I solve a similar problem?

Comment: In this case the exercise is easier because the canonical statistic is CSS

Comment: Oh, thanks! Can you recommend any text where you address these issues of inferential statistics from the point of view of mathematical statistics? Thanks a lot

Comment: First best: Casella Berger; second best: Mood Graybill Boes (IMHO)

Comment: Consider the density $f(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$. $S=\Sigma x$ is CSS and  $T=\frac{n-1}{\Sigma x}$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and function of $S$. Thus T is UMVUE for $\theta$

Comment: Thank so much tommik :-)